# Excel scatter plot x axis displays only sequential numbers but not real data selected for x axis

Tags: excel-charts, sequential-number

I have an excel scatter plot with 5 different data series on single chart. First 4 series are working well. When I want to add a new series with similar x-axis data (0.0, 0.4, 0.9 .. ) the plot is displayed with x-axis values as 1,2,3 but not as the data specified.
Changing the chart types did not help. Not sure how can I get the x-axis as data but not as sequential numbers. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Added the screenshot of chart and its xaxis data. The values are in number format only just as data for other series. Everytime I am adding a new series on to this, its starting with one number later.... (1,2,3...) next series x axis at (2,3,4....) but not with real x values as selected.[image]

Comment: I could fix it... The problem is X-axis range is for 18 cells and all the cells had formula with IF condition...      When I removed the IF condition, x-axis worked well as numbers

Answer (score 1):

Solved it my slef... The problem is X-axis range is for 18 cells and all the cells had formula with IF condition...      When I removed the IF condition, x-axis worked well as numbers
The IF condition I used was "=IF(A10<>"",B10=A10-A4,""), for some reason excel chart considered this as some text and populated the x axis as 1,2,3 but not as the values specified.

Comment: I had this same problem, the Google gods directed my query to this post, and your observation solved my problem. I wasn't on the path to discovering this on my own.